# Switch javascript on element ID selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to simplify the javascript code not to repeat the functions as many times as an id element is present? I also found it difficult to add the CSS selector #selected on Balide li clicked.

```js
function LightBlue() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].setAttribute("id", "LightBlue");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'Black'; 
}       
function MorningSalad() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].setAttribute("id", "MorningSalad");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'Black'; 
}
function AngelCare() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].setAttribute("id", "AngelCare");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'Black'; 
}
function GrassShampoo() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].setAttribute("id", "GrassShampoo");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'Black'; 
}

etc...

document.getElementById('LightBlue').onclick = LightBlue;
document.getElementById('MorningSalad').onclick = MorningSalad;
document.getElementById('AngelCare').onclick = AngelCare;
document.getElementById('GrassShampoo').onclick = GrassShampoo;

etc...
```

```css
body{margin:3em;padding:0;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:18px;line-height:1.5;height:1500px;margin-top:50px}
h1{line-height:1.25;margin:2em 0 0}
p{margin:.5em 0}
li:hover{cursor:pointer}
#switcher{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden}
#switcher li{float:left;width:30px;height:30px;margin:0 15px 15px 0;border-radius:30px;border:3px solid #000}
.selected{opacity:.2}

#LightBlue{background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#9EFBD3 0%,#57E9F2 48%,#45D4FB 100%)}
#MorningSalad{background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#B7F8DB 0%,#50A7C2 100%)}
#AngelCare{background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#FFE29F 0%,#FFA99F 48%,#FF719A 100%)}
#GrassShampoo{background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#DFFFCD 0%,#90F9C4 48%,#39F3BB 100%)}
#SeaLord{background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#2CD8D5 0%,#C5C1FF 56%,#FFBAC3 100%)}
#SunVeggie{background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#20E2D7 0%,#F9FEA5 100%)}
#RoyalGarden{background-image:linear-gradient(to right,#ed6ea0 0%,#ec8c69 100%)}
#HighFlight{background:linear-gradient(to right,#0acffe 0%,#495aff 100%)}
#AfricanField{background:linear-gradient(-45deg,#FFC796 0%,#FF6B95 100%)}
#HappyUnicorn{background:linear-gradient(to top,#b3ffab 0%,#12fff7 100%)}
#ColorfulPeach{background:linear-gradient(to right,#ed6ea0 0%,#ec8c69 100%)}
#YoungGrass{background:linear-gradient(to top,#9be15d 0%,#00e3ae 100%)}
#Seashore{background-image:linear-gradient(to top,#209cff 0%,#68e0cf 100%)}
#FlyingLemon{background:linear-gradient(60deg,#64b3f4 0%,#c2e59c 100%)}
#HealthyWater{background:linear-gradient(60deg,#96deda 0%,#50c9c3 100%)}
#PassionateBed{background:linear-gradient(to right,#ff758c 0%,#ff7eb3 100%)}
#SummerGames{background:linear-gradient(to right,#92fe9d 0%,#00c9ff 100%)}
#ShadyWater{background:linear-gradient(to right,#74ebd5 0%,#9face6 100%)}
#FlyHigh{background:linear-gradient(to top,#48c6ef 0%,#6f86d6 100%)}
#StrongBliss{background:linear-gradient(to right,#f78ca0 0%,#f9748f 19%,#fd868c 60%,#fe9a8b 100%)}
#HappyAcid{background:linear-gradient(to top,#37ecba 0%,#72afd3 100%)}
#ItmeoBranding{background:linear-gradient(180deg,#2af598 0%,#009efd 100%)}
#LemonGate{background:linear-gradient(to top,#96fbc4 0%,#f9f586 100%)}
#SharpeyeEagle{background:linear-gradient(to top,#9890e3 0%,#b1f4cf 100%)}
#Blessing{background:linear-gradient(to top,#fddb92 0%,#d1fdff 100%)}
#HappyFisher{background:linear-gradient(120deg,#89f7fe 0%,#66a6ff 100%)}
#AriellesSmile{background:radial-gradient(circle 248px at center,#16d9e3 0%,#30c7ec 47%,#46aef7 100%)}
#NearMoon{background:linear-gradient(to top,#5ee7df 0%,#b490ca 100%)}
#TrueSunset{background:linear-gradient(to right,#fa709a 0%,#fee140 100%)}
#NewLife{background:linear-gradient(to right,#43e97b 0%,#38f9d7 100%)}
#MalibuBeach{background:linear-gradient(to right,#4facfe 0%,#00f2fe 100%)}
#DeepBlue{background:linear-gradient(120deg,#e0c3fc 0%,#8ec5fc 100%)}
#WinterNeva{background:linear-gradient(120deg,#a1c4fd 0%,#c2e9fb 100%)}
#SunnyMorning{background:linear-gradient(120deg,#f6d365 0%,#fda085 100%)}
#TemptingAzure{background:linear-gradient(120deg,#84fab0 0%,#8fd3f4 100%)}
```

```html
<ul id="switcher">
    <li id="LightBlue"></li>
    <li id="MorningSalad"></li>
    <li id="AngelCare"></li>
    <li id="GrassShampoo"></li>
    <li id="SeaLord"></li>
    <li id="SunVeggie"></li>
    <li id="RoyalGarden"></li>
    <li id="HighFlight"></li>
    <li id="AfricanField"></li>
    <li id="HappyUnicorn"></li>
    <li id="ColorfulPeach"></li>
    <li id="YoungGrass"></li>
    <li id="Seashore"></li>
    <li id="FlyingLemon"></li>
    <li id="HealthyWater"></li>
    <li id="PassionateBed"></li>
    <li id="SummerGames"></li>
    <li id="ShadyWater"></li>
    <li id="FlyHigh"></li>
    <li id="StrongBliss"></li>
    <li id="HappyAcid"></li>
    <li id="ItmeoBranding"></li>
    <li id="LemonGate"></li>
    <li id="SharpeyeEagle"></li>
    <li id="Blessing"></li>
    <li id="HappyFisher"></li>
    <li id="AriellesSmile"></li>
    <li id="NearMoon"></li>
    <li id="TrueSunset"></li>
    <li id="NewLife"></li>
    <li id="MalibuBeach"></li>
    <li id="DeepBlue"></li>
    <li id="WinterNeva"></li>
    <li id="SunnyMorning"></li>
    <li id="TemptingAzure"></li>
</ul>
 
<h1>What's your favorite color ?</h1>   
<p>Try clicking on one of the above colors to change the colors on this page!</p>
```

Comment: Please add only needed code

Comment: That code doesn't make a lot of sense I'm afraid. You're responding to a click on an element with `id="LightBlue"` by changing the `id` of the `body` element to `LightBlue`, which makes the document invalid (you can only have one element with a given `id`)...?

Comment: Side note: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` can be written `document.body`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the buttons themselves to hold the value to change to, then assign one function to listen for clicks on all of them:

e: Or use class swapping, per good suggestion. Excercise left to reader to not clear out any important classnames.

```js
let changers = document.querySelectorAll('.changer');
changers.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        // document.body.style.backgroundColor = e.target.getAttribute('data-color');
        // or as css class
        document.body.className="";
        document.body.classList.add( e.target.getAttribute('data-colourclass') )
    })
});
```

```css
.LightBlue{background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#9EFBD3 0%,#57E9F2 48%,#45D4FB 100%)}
.MorningSalad{background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#B7F8DB 0%,#50A7C2 100%)}
.AngelCare{background:linear-gradient(-225deg,#FFE29F 0%,#FFA99F 48%,#FF719A 100%)}
```

```html
<li class='changer' data-colourclass="LightBlue">LightBlue</li>
<li class='changer' data-colourclass="AngelCare">AngelCare</li>
<li class='changer' data-colourclass="MorningSalad" >MorningSalad</li>
```

Comment: Just FWIW, `document.body.className=""; document.body.classList.add( e.target.getAttribute('data-colourclass') )` can be `document.body.className = e.target.getAttribute('data-colourclass');`

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer by Gavin, but thought you might also be interested in this:

If you have a few functions that you want to be able to call by their string-name, you should just use an object like this:

```
function a() {}

function b() {}

const funcList = {
  'a': a,
  'b': b
}


// then call the function by string name:
funcList['a']();
funcList['b']();
```

You can also define the function directly inside the object if that's preferred:

```
const funcList = {
  'a': function() {},
  'b': function() {}
}
```